# R - Using Duplicate Keys to Replace NA's with Dates

Tags: r, date, dplyr, lubridate

I have several hundred duplicated primary keys and dates that are associated with these keys. Dates may or may not have missing entries, but need missing entries do need to be replaced with the max(date).

```
#Create Proxy dataframe
df <- tibble(
  key = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d", "e", "e", "f", "f", "h", "h", "i","i", "j", "j", "k", "k", "l", "l", "m", "m"),
  date1 = c("NA", "2017-02-13", "NA", "2017-04-14", "2017-05-18", "2017-05-18", "NA", "2018-01-07",
          "2017-09-24", "2017-09-25", "NA", "2017-09-29", "NA", "2017-08-13", "NA", "2017-04-29",
          "NA", "2018-01-28", "NA", "2017-10-08", "NA", "2017-01-10", "NA", "2017-11-01")
)
df$date1 <- as.Date(df$date1, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Note that

-key "a" has a missing date and needs to be replaced with the only available date
-key "c" does not have any missing dates
-key "e" has two different dates, but the last date needs to be recorded

```
 df
    # A tibble: 24 x 2
         key      date1
       <chr>     <date>
     1     a         NA
     2     a 2017-02-13
     3     b         NA
     4     b 2017-04-14
     5     c 2017-05-18
     6     c 2017-05-18
     7     d         NA
     8     d 2018-01-07
     9     e 2017-09-24
    10     e 2017-09-25
    # ... with 14 more rows
```

Solutions that I have tried that do not work:

```
library(lubridate)
df$date <- with(df$date, as.Date(ifelse(is.na(df$date), orderDate, df$date), origin = "1970-01-01"))

library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(key) %>%
        mutate(date = (date, NA, df$date)) %>%
        as.data.frame
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just want to replace with the `max()` value within each group when `date1` is NA, this will work. Note that you need to specify `na.rm = TRUE`, because `max(NA, 1)` returns NA, rather than 1.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(key) %>% 
  mutate(Date = case_when(
    is.na(date1) ~ max(date1, na.rm = TRUE), 
    TRUE ~ date1)
  )

# A tibble: 24 x 3
# Groups:   key [12]
     key      date1       Date
   <chr>     <date>     <date>
 1     a         NA 2017-02-13
 2     a 2017-02-13 2017-02-13
 3     b         NA 2017-04-14
 4     b 2017-04-14 2017-04-14
 5     c 2017-05-18 2017-05-18
 6     c 2017-05-18 2017-05-18
 7     d         NA 2018-01-07
 8     d 2018-01-07 2018-01-07
 9     e 2017-09-24 2017-09-24
10     e 2017-09-25 2017-09-25
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative approach which is much faster than [Mako212's `dplyr` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49520183/3817004). It uses an *update while joining* to replace the `NA` values with the `max(date1)` for each `key` group:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
tmp <- DT[, .(date1 = as.Date(NA), max(date1, na.rm = TRUE)), by = key]
DT[tmp, on = .(key, date1), date1 := V2][]
```

> ```
>     key      date1
>  1:   a 2017-02-13
>  2:   a 2017-02-13
>  3:   b 2017-04-14
>  4:   b 2017-04-14
>  5:   c 2017-05-18
>  6:   c 2017-05-18
>  7:   d 2018-01-07
>  8:   d 2018-01-07
>  9:   e 2017-09-24
> 10:   e 2017-09-25
> 11:   f 2017-09-29
> 12:   f 2017-09-29
> 13:   h 2017-08-13
> 14:   h 2017-08-13
> 15:   i 2017-04-29
> 16:   i 2017-04-29
> 17:   j 2018-01-28
> 18:   j 2018-01-28
> 19:   k 2017-10-08
> 20:   k 2017-10-08
> 21:   l 2017-01-10
> 22:   l 2017-01-10
> 23:   m 2017-11-01
> 24:   m 2017-11-01
>     key      date1
> ```

Note that only rows where `date1` is `NA` are replaced *in place*, i.e., without copying the whole data object.

`tmp` contains the replacemnet values for each `key` group:

> ```
>     key date1         V2
>  1:   a  <NA> 2017-02-13
>  2:   b  <NA> 2017-04-14
>  3:   c  <NA> 2017-05-18
>  4:   d  <NA> 2018-01-07
>  5:   e  <NA> 2017-09-25
>  6:   f  <NA> 2017-09-29
>  7:   h  <NA> 2017-08-13
>  8:   i  <NA> 2017-04-29
>  9:   j  <NA> 2018-01-28
> 10:   k  <NA> 2017-10-08
> 11:   l  <NA> 2017-01-10
> 12:   m  <NA> 2017-11-01
> ```

#### Benchmark

Create benchmark data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
n_row <- 1e5L
n_key <- 500L
share_na <- 0.5
set.seed(123L)
DT0 <- data.table(
  key1 = sprintf("%04i", sample.int(n_key, n_row, TRUE)),
  date1 = as.Date("2017-01-01") + sample.int(n_key, n_row, TRUE)
)
# set NA values
DT0[sample.int(n_row, share_na * n_row), date1 := NA]
# coerce to tibble
df0 <- as_tibble(DT0)
```

Run benchmark:

```
library(microbenchmark)
bm <- microbenchmark(
  dplyr = {
    copy(df0) %>% group_by(key1) %>% 
      mutate(date1 = case_when(
        is.na(date1) ~ max(date1, na.rm = TRUE), 
        TRUE ~ date1)
      )
    },
  dt = {
    DT <- copy(DT0)
    tmp <- DT[, .(date1 = as.Date(NA), max(date1, na.rm = TRUE)), by = key1]
    DT[tmp, on = .(key1, date1), date1 := V2][]
  },
  times = 21L
)
print(bm)
```

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
>  dplyr 131.02040 136.81967 142.63845 137.78741 141.36084 191.37755    21   b
>     dt  18.14997  18.68349  19.65384  19.32424  19.54815  26.87965    21  a
> ```

For the given problem size of 100 k rows, 500 groups, and 50% of `NA` values, the `data.table` approach is about 7 times faster than the `dplyr` version.

Note that a fresh copy of `DT0` and `df0` is used for each repetition because `DT` is updated in place. The call to `copy()` is included in the timing of both cases. The `dplyr` version has been amended to update the `date1` instead of creating a third column in the output.